# Can Blender work with 4k video?

Tags: edit-mode, video

Hi I am a huge fan of Blender. I've been using it to edit video perfectly.
Since recently I need to edit 4k mov files. (each strip is between 1 or 2 gb) And it is too slow to work with. I noticed that when rebuilding proxy and timecode indices Blender is only using one (of the 8) cores. (well it looks like it. it only uses 19-20% of its processor)

I am working on a Intel Core i7-4720HQ quadcore 256g ssd with NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M, 2GB/4GB DDR3 VRAM

Is there any solution so I can keep working with Blender?

Comment: The VSE can't be used with multiple cores. You should use proxies for your strips to be able to edit more smoothly.

Comment: When you say "slow to work with" are you referring to rendering or playback?

Comment: with 'slow to work with' I mean impossible to edit. Even with proxy size of 25% blender hardly responds.
Maybe my question should be: Can I or How can I work with 4k video in Blender?

Comment: Do not use Blender's VSE unless it's really simple thing you need to do. There are far better free video editors out there. Blender is not capable of handling 4K, maybe in the future. Check the DaVinci Resolve Lite or Fusion7 or also Natron.

Comment: Yes you can use 4K images in the VSE..., but why would you want to put yourself in such a painful situation? I totally agree with @Jerryno: the VSE is not as developed as most video editing apps available today. Even some of the most basic apps are more responsive. Resolve is free and a very powerful editing tool (multi-threaded and uses GPU accereation). Where I don't agree with the previous post is that Fusion and Natron are not video editors but compositnig apps.

Comment: @Samoth False.  If I have powerful hardware, the software should use it, or I am going to look elsewhere for something that *can*.  I feel like this is borderline abuse.